# What exactly is the value of a boost::scoped_ptr pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I am trying to understand the syntaxis of `boost::scoped_ptr`. Let's define and write to standard output a `scoped_ptr` pointer as well as the value it points at:

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::scoped_ptr<int> p{new int{1}};

  std::cout << p.get() << '\n'; // ok
  std::cout << p << '\n';       // error   


  std::cout << *p.get() << '\n'; // ok
  std::cout << *p << '\n';       // ok. *p==*p.get()
}
```

**Question.** Why is `*p.get()==*p` and yet `std::cout << p << '\n';` won't compile?

I'm working `on g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic`.

Comment: Question 1 is like having: `int* p;` and asking why `p` isn't equal to `&p`. Why would the address of the pointer be equal to the address stored in it?

Comment: If you have C++11, prefer `std::unique_ptr` to `boost::scoped_ptr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why do `&p` and `p.get()` produce different results?

`&p` is the address of the `scoped_ptr` object. `p.get()` is the address of  the `int` object it points to.

> Why is `*p.get()==*p` and yet `std::cout << p << '\n';` won't compile?

The two are unrelated.

`*p` is defined to be the same as `*p.get()`: dereferencing a scoped pointer accesses the object it points to, and so does dereferencing a raw pointer to the same object.

`cout << p` doesn't compile because there's no overload of `<<` for streaming scoped pointers.

> I'm working on `g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic`

Then consider `std::unique_ptr` (introduced in C++11) rather than `boost::scoped_ptr`. It's more standard, and also movable.

Answer (score 1):

`scoped_ptr` or any other "smart pointers" are something "pointer like objects" instead of real pointers.

These smart pointers are actually objects, of course `&p`, which obtains a pointer to this "smart pointer object", is different from `p.get()`, which is a method returns the pointer that the "smart pointer object" holds.

`*p.get()` is equivalent to `*(p.get())`, where `p.get()` returns the pointer that `p` holds, and `*p` is equivalent to "p.operator*()", which is an overloaded operator, also returns the pointer that `p` holds, that's why `*p.get()==*p`.

`cout << p` doesn't compile as there is no overloaded operator that outputs `p` to a stream.

Answer (score 1):

*scoped_ptr< T >* is a template class mimicking a pointer. Instantiation of this class will create an object which has similar behaviors as pointers.

- `p.get` returns the address of the associated value of type `T*`: so it returns the address returned by `new int{1}`, that is the value in its member which points to the associated pointer.
- `&p` return the address of object *p* (that is, where *p* resides). *p* is a container which has a true pointer member which points on the address of the associated value of type T.
- `p` cannot return anything good because `scoped_ptr< T >` has no cast operator to convert itself into `T*` by design choice. You must use *get* for this purpose. But it should give a bool-like answer in a conditional expression equivalent to `p.get() != 0`.
- `cout << p` fails because there is no stream operators defined for *scoped_ptr< T >*.
- `*p` exists because there is a defined unary operator* which gives the same result as `*(p.get())`